# Permission is denied even though users press okay

Tags: ios, facebook

```
        PO (self.ACAccounts);
        PO([self dicReadOptions]);
        [self.ACAstore requestAccessToAccountsWithType:self.ACAccounts options:[self dicReadOptions] completion:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error) {
            self.bPermissionToAccessStoreGranted=granted;
            [self vContinue];
        }];

2014-01-21 12:59:20.947 [460:60b] self.ACAccounts: identifier: com.apple.facebook
description: Facebook
objectID: x-coredata://5E844BD2-BC4C-4807-924F-F6A6ACBA9F45/AccountType/p5
supportsAuthentication YES
supportsMultipleAccounts NO
supportedDataclasses {(
    "com.apple.Dataclass.Calendars",
    "com.apple.Dataclass.Contacts"
)}
syncableDataclasses (null)
2014-01-21 12:59:35.490 [460:60b] [self dicReadOptions]: {
    ACFacebookAppIdKey = 115372328641884;
    ACFacebookAudienceKey = everyone;
    ACFacebookPermissionsKey =     (
        "user_about_me",
        "friends_about_me",
        "user_activities",
        "friends_activities",
        "user_birthday",
        "friends_birthday",
        "user_checkins",
        "friends_checkins",
        "user_education_history",
        "friends_education_history",
        "user_events",
        "friends_events",
        "user_groups",
        "friends_groups",
        "user_hometown",
        "friends_hometown",
        "user_interests",
        "friends_interests",
        "user_likes",
        "friends_likes",
        "user_notes",
        "friends_notes",
        "user_online_presence",
        "friends_online_presence",
        "user_interests",
        "friends_interests",
        "user_likes",
        "friends_likes",
        "user_notes",
        "friends_notes",
        "user_online_presence",
        "friends_online_presence",
        "user_religion_politics",
        "friends_religion_politics",
        "user_status",
        "friends_status",
        "user_subscriptions",
        "friends_subscriptions",
        "user_videos",
        "friends_videos",
        "user_website",
        "friends_website",
        "user_work_history",
        "friends_work_history",
        "read_friendlists",
        "read_mailbox",
        "read_requests",
        "read_stream",
        "read_insights",
        "xmpp_login",
        email
    );
}
```

How can it be? The user clearly press Okay when asked for permission. Yet the value of granted is false.

Now the completion block is simply never called.

Note: It used to work!

Actually it just happened today. Before it all works.

This may be the issue. But where in the function of self.ACAStore requestAccessToAccountsWithType we specify our APPID?

Comment: Is your app still in sandbox mode on the Facebook developer site? If so only approved accounts (developers and testers) will successfully authenticate.

Comment: The app is fine. In fact, it works simulator

Comment: So, you're saying that the this code works in the simulator, but not on a real device, using the exact same Facebook account?

Comment: Actually it doesn't work anywhere now starting today I think

Answer (score 1):

I found out what the problem was. I just change my bundle id. So I need to update my facebook app to work with the new bundle id.

Facebook needs to know which apps provide the stuffs.